# Replacement for VP-BC73E Bottom Bracket

Tags: maintenance, repair, bottom-bracket, parts, replacement

I cannot find my bottom bracket online anywhere. It's called "VP-BC73E ". However, I can find loads of "VP-BC73" (E is missing). Would it still fit/work?

I found this information on the VP website but not sure what it means:

- VP-BC73
- VP-BC73C for chain guard stay mount plate.
- VP-BC73A Cold forged aluminum cups.
- VP-BC73E for front derailleur BB mount plate.
- VP-BC73T Axle with chainline stopper ring

Can I go ahead and purchase the VP-BC73 enough though the one that came out of the bike is called VP-BC73E?

Comment: Do you have a front-derauilleur? How is your derailleur mounted? Bolted to braze-ons on the seat tube? Clamped to the seat tube? Or attached using a bracket-like contraption to your BB? A picture would help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your original BB was VP-BC73E, then all of the options you listed will fit your frame.

The difference between VP-BC73C, VP-BC73E is the ability to bolt on different items directly to the BB:

- VP-BC73C for chain guard stay mount plate.
- VP-BC73E for front derailleur BB mount plate.

If you have none of those in your existing setup, then you should be fine with any variation of VP-BC73. Make sure you pick the one with the correct axle length. The axle length will be printed on the sleeve of your original BB.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your answer. Very grateful